# How to fill input with jQuery on input click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a widget that I'm trying to pre-populate with data, but I do not have access to the widget code, only its HTML elements:

[image]

The following code properly takes the email (passed through the URL) and updates the email address input:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

var email = getUrlParameter('email');
console.log(email);
$('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('input[name="email"]').val(email);
```

What I'm trying to do, since I cannot add an "on click" functionality of entering the widget, is I want to update that input field when the field is clicked on with the cursor.

Given the jQuery that properly selects the input element inside of the iframe that contains the widget, how would I do this? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$('#ticketSubmissionForm').contents().find('input[name="email"]').click(function(){
    var change = $(this).val(email);
    console.log(change);
});
```

but that does not seem to work

Comment: Did you get any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that the jQuery was executing before the widget could load entirely, thus making the jQuery statement undefined. Adding in a delay fixed the issue